# how to use selenium webdriver get the data file and put it in variable with python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, urllib2

I dont know why my urllib2 urlopen  is useless.So I use selenium webdriver to get the data.

With urlopen,I do this:

```
import urllib2
import time
url="http://maia.usno.navy.mil/ser7/deltat.data"
req_header = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11','Accept':'text/html;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8','Accept-Charset':'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3','Accept-Encoding':'gzip','Connection':'close','Referer':None }
req_timeout = 10
req = urllib2.Request(url,None,req_header)
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req,None,req_timeout)
t=resp.read().decode('utf-8','ignore')
time.sleep(3)
print resp
```

And it makes lots of error  such as error 10060,10061......
SO I try to use the webdriver,my code is :

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Ie()
url ="http://maia.usno.navy.mil/ser7/deltat.data"
print dir(browser)
c=browser.get(url)
```

I want to get the dalta.data content into the variable c
[the wetset and the file i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBrnI.png)

Comment: It works with urlopen. I use python2.7

Comment: it works `>>>c=urllib2.urlopen("http://maia.usno.navy.mil/ser7/deltat.data") >>> c.read()` output-sample:`' 1973  2  1  43.4724\n 1973  3  1  43.5648\n 1973  4  1  43.6737\n`

Comment: ohh，The code is correct . But I still can't read the data and I can get the data file with the firfox brower. Why？I am going mad~~

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the content present in some web element. Try following code snippet.

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/pre')

# Now extract text from that element.
c = elem.text
```

Comment: yes .with this code I have got the data . But i still wonder why the urlopen doesn't work~~.for i am in CHN?